# SQL - How do I search for "weight" within CONTAINS?

Tags: sql, vb.net, contains

We have a full-text index setup to allow searching a directory for PDF files containing specified text. I've been getting notifications that's it's blowing up when people are searching for "weight loss" and I need to fix it. Right now I look at the user's input and just remove anything that's not a letter or number and build a string to pass to the CONTAINS function. I tried wrapping weight in additional quotes to try to show I'm not specifying a keyword but that didn't work. Is there anything I can do to get around this? Here's the VB.NET string I'm using to test `searchString = """weight"" and loss"`

Comment: People are searching for `"weight loss"` or `weight loss`? You can always check if there are quotes around it and remove them as needed.

Comment: I'm already checking for that. I add AND or OR to my search string based on if the original query is wrapped in quotes. It's not the quotes that are the problem, it's the word weight because CONTAINS thinks I'm trying to specify an option, not search for something.

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. I ended up checking if the input contains the word weight, then I wrapped it in quotes. There query string generated has this CONTAINS statement which works. `Where CONTAINS(Contents, '"WEIGHT" OR LOSS')`. I was initially passing the query string in without the single quotes and it wasn't working.